# ASP.net Identity management with Azure, in Web Form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, asp.net-identity, owin-middleware

I have a Webform ASP.net (in VB.net) that I want to add identity management too.  I have added code that allows for the registration of users.  But, I am stuck on how to log a user in.  My application uses SSO with Azure Active Directory.  What I would like to do is, after the user Authenticates with Azure, then use Identity management to see if the user is in the web system and if they have roles.

This site can be accessed by three types of users:  1) Internal folks who would have a local account as well as an Azure AD account, who act as admins for the site 2) Internal folks who authenticate with Azure AD, but will not have local accounts (i.e authenticated but with no roles)  3) External folks who will not authenticate with Azure AD and will not have local accounts

My questions is, how do I use Identity management, after the users authenticates with Azure AD?  Here is my code:

**Startup.Auth.vb:**

```
Partial Public Class Startup
    Dim appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

    Private realm As String
    Private aadInstance As String
    Private tenant As String
    Private metadata As String
    Private authority As String

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)        
            Dim appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings            
            realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RPIdentifier")
            aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance")
            tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")  
            metadata = String.Format("{0}/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml", aadInstance)
            authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant)

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
            Dim authOption As WsFederationAuthenticationOptions = New WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()

            Dim fn = Function(context)
                         context.HandleResponse()
                         context.Response.Redirect("Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message)
                         Return Task.FromResult(0)
                     End Function

            Dim auth_not As WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications = New WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                    .AuthenticationFailed = fn
                 }

            Dim auth_opt As WsFederationAuthenticationOptions = New WsFederationAuthenticationOptions() With {
                 .Wtrealm = realm,
                 .MetadataAddress = metadata,
                 .Notifications = auth_not
               }
             app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(auth_opt)


    End Sub   

End Class
```

**Default.aspx.vb login click:**

```
Public Sub SignIn()             
   Dim newAuth As AuthenticationProperties = New AuthenticationProperties()            
   newAuth.RedirectUri = "/" 

   HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(newAuth, WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)                                                                                               

    End Sub
```

The problem is, I don't know where to user the UserManager to get the logged in user, after the user gets redirected to our companies log in page, and they are redirected back to the site, with the returned Azure AD Username.